# SQL Table Value Parameter only works when its data is copied to temporary table

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters

I'm passing the data through c# to sql stored procedure using dapper.

c# (using dapper):

```
 var dt = new DataTable("dbo.TVPtype");
 dt.SetTypeName("dbo.TVPtype");
 dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
 dt.Rows.Add(5);
_db.Execute("mysp", param: new { TVP = dt.AsTableValuedParameter("dbo.TVPtype"), commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

The bellow SQL query will not work and I don't know Why! And it removes all data from mytable.
SQL stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[mysp] @TVP dbo.TVPtype READONLY AS
DELETE FROM [dbo].[mytable] WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT NULL FROM @TVP na
WHERE ID = na.ID
)
```

To solve the problem I've used a temporary table in the stored procedure like bellow, and it works well.
My solution using temporary table:

```
CREATE table temptb (ID int)
insert into temptb select * from @TVP
```

Now I use temptb instead of @TVP in the delete query:

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[mytable] WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT NULL FROM temptb na
WHERE ID = na.ID
)
```

It works well and delete specific data (not all data) !
So what's wrong with my first query?

Comment: First, find out if the problem is in c# or in SQL - try to run the first stored procedure directly from SSMS and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you, why it's working with temporary table, but the problem comes from the DELETE statement if you change it to:

```
DELETE t1 
FROM [dbo].[mytable] AS t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT NULL FROM @TVP na
    WHERE t1.ID = na.ID
)
```

It will work. See, that when I add alias to `mytable` condition becomes clear which ID's it should compare. When in your example it might compare `@TVP` ID with it self(that's my guess).

I want to add two more points to your query:

1. It's better to select something that is not NULL when you check for existence, as NULL is special in SQL(although it is working in your example). For example `SELECT 1 FROM @TVP...` would be more readable
2. Why not to do it like this:

Snippet:

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[mytable] AS t1 WHERE ID NOT IN
(
    SELECT na.ID FROM @TVP na
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Qualify your column names!  You think you are writing:

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[mytable]
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM @TVP na
                      WHERE mytable.ID = na.ID
                     );
```

But you are not.  The scoping rules of SQL interpret your query as:

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[mytable]
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM @TVP na
                      WHERE na.ID = na.ID
                     );
```

This is rather non-sensical.  The `WHERE` is not correlated to the outer query.  It will delete either all rows (if `@TVP` is empty or the `ID` is always `NULL`) or no rows (any other situation).

If you qualify *all* column references, you will never have this problem.